# Create new variable using vectors of upper and lower bounds

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,1,3,4,5], columns=['data'])
```

and a set of categories and bounds:

```
catBounds = pd.DataFrame([['a',1,2],
                          ['b',3,4]],
                         columns=['cat','lb','ub'])
```

that I would like to add a column of categories to the first DataFrame where if the value lies between bounds 1 and 2, the new column is assigned "a" and if the value lies between the bounds 3 and 4, the new column is assigned "b". An inelegant way of doing this would be to loop over the rows of `catBounds` and making assignments:

```
for index, row in catBounds.iterrows():
    df.loc[(df.data>=row.lb) & (df.data<=row.ub), 'cat'] = row['cat']
```

getting:

|  | data | cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a |
| 1 | 2 | a |
| 2 | 1 | a |
| 3 | 3 | b |
| 4 | 4 | b |
| 5 | 5 | NaN |

Is there a cleaner, more Pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to `melt` `catBounds` to create a mapping from category to bounds, then use `map`:

```
df['cat'] = df['data'].map(catBounds.melt('cat').set_index('value')['cat'])
```

A more general approach could be to use `numpy.select`:

```
import numpy as np
df['cat'] = np.select([df['data'].between(lb, ub) for lb,ub in zip(catBounds['lb'], catBounds['ub'])], catBounds['cat'], np.nan)
```

Output:

```
   data  cat
0     1    a
1     2    a
2     1    a
3     3    b
4     4    b
5     5  NaN
```

Comment: The map option  works for exact matches, not sure it would suffice  if the lower bounds or upper bounds were not exact matches

Comment: Your second option worked great and was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the data and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge):

```
df.merge(catBounds
         .melt(id_vars='cat', value_name='data')
         .drop(columns='variable'),
         on='data', how='left')
```

Output:

```
   data  cat
0     1    a
1     2    a
2     1    a
3     3    b
4     4    b
5     5  NaN
```

Comment: This works for exact matches, not sure if the results would be correcy the lower bounds or upper bounds were not exact matches

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a non-equi join - specifically a range join; one option is the [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to get the relevant data:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
# you can install the dev version as well
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import janitor
import pandas as pd

(df
.conditional_join(
    catBounds, 
    # col from left, col from right, comparator
    ('data', 'lb', '>='), 
    ('data', 'ub', '<='), 
    how = 'left')
.loc[:, ['data', 'cat']]
)

   data  cat
0     1    a
1     2    a
2     1    a
3     3    b
4     4    b
5     5  NaN
```

If your bounds are exact matches, there is no point using this, a merge or map will be more efficient